# macOS: find last time AirPods Bluetooth headphones were connected/in the range

Tags: macos, bluetooth, logs, time-tracking

I have either lost my AirPods either someone stole them, and I would like to find more details to find which possibilities is most likely.

Unfortunately my AirPods are not listed under Find My (probably I forgot to activate that function). So what remains is to check the last time I was using them/they were in the Bluetooth range of my Mac.

In this precise moment I can ask my Mac to give me the list of visible (both connected and not) Bluetooth devices, the question is: **is the history (time included) of connected/visible bluetooth devices logged somewhere in macOS?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to do `brew install blueutil` and then use the recent command: `blueutil --recent` to get the mac address of my airpods then use the info command:

```
blueutil --info fc-1d-43-b9-8f-05
address: fc-1d-43-b9-8f-05, not connected, not favourite, paired, 
name: "James’s AirPods Pro", recent access date: 2021-05-26 18:36:22 +0000
```

this gives you the recent access date and time. Hope this helps!

Comment: WOW! If I could give you 10 upvotes I would! Btw I did find the AirPods in the end, but this would have helped me a lot!

Comment: Glad you found them @Nisba I didn't find mine unfortunately but I have a new pair :)