# Get Bluetooth (AirPods) logs

Tags: logs, find-my-iphone, airpods

I am trying to find the last location of my lost AirPods.
Is there a chance to find a log file in my iPhone showing the last connection with them?

I do not have a macOS in order to use this solution [macOS: find last time AirPods Bluetooth headphones were connected/in the range](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/409512/macos-find-last-time-airpods-bluetooth-headphones-were-connected-in-the-range).

Many thanks